# In django template urls are imported correctly but don't work

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, django-userena

I am a total noob in Django, so it might seem I may miss something obvious.

I am using django userena app. Following official documentationv I include userena urls like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
   url(r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
   # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

And when I try to use some URL in my template they load correctly, but don't work.

```
        <div class="search_button" type="submit">
            Find
        </div>
        <div href="{% url 'userena_signin' %}" class="enter">
            Sign in
        </div>
        <div href="{% url 'userena_signup' %}" class="enter">
            Sign up
        </div>
```

When i load the page I can see correct URL

```
        <div href="/accounts/signin/" class="enter">
            Sign in
        </div>
        <div href="/accounts/signup/" class="enter">
            Sign up
        </div>
```

but pushing the button doesn't lead to neither sign in page, nor sign up.
What did I miss?

Comment: Looks like you did not closed this question yet, I guess you forgot but may be there you are still thinking about it ? is everything ok ?

Comment: Everything ok! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

href need to be applied on a [< a > markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a) . You are using it on a div.

Here is a correct version :

```
<div class="search_button" type="submit">
    Find
</div>
<a href="{% url 'userena_signin' %}" class="enter">
    Sign in
</a>
<a href="{% url 'userena_signup' %}" class="enter">
    Sign up
</a>
```

Also < div type="submit" > normally apply on a < input /> markup, but may be you have some code fixing that I don't know.

Seems to be pure HTML issue, nothing related to Django which is correctly used here ;)

Comment: Yes, I ommited that part! Thanks a lot! A lesson for me to dive into HTML too.

Comment: Ahah, no problem, your question was well written so it was easy to understand and find it :D